# Repeating Table Headers in HTML

Tags: php, html, css

I have a large dataset from MySQL that I am displaying using PHP. If the user tries to print it, it has some 50 pages of data.

The entire data is displayed using tables and simple PHP `echo-s` that display the data in the table fields.

What I need is - when a user tries to print it OR export to PDF in Safari (Mac), the table headers should appear on all pages. How can this be done?

Thanks

Edit: I have enclosed the table headers under  but it doesnt work. It's a plain HTML page with no scripts that just displays data from database.

**Code**

```
echo "<table border='1'>
<thead>
<tr>
<th></th>
<th></th>
<th></th>
<th></th>
<th colspan=13>Item Info</th>
<th colspan=4>Lot Info</th>
</tr>
<tr>
<th bgcolor='#C8E3FF'>S.No.</th>
<th bgcolor='#C8E3FF'>Party Name</th>
<th bgcolor='#C8E3FF'>Item No.</th>
<th bgcolor='#C8E3FF'>Date</th>

<th>Flower</th>

<th bgcolor='#C8E3FF'>Lot No.</th>
<th bgcolor='#C8E3FF'>Avg Wt.</th>
<th bgcolor='#C8E3FF'>Total Weight</th>
<th bgcolor='#C8E3FF'>Detail Page</th>
</tr></thead><tfoot></tfoot><tbody>";

    echo "<tr>";
    echo "<td bgcolor='#C8E3FF' rowspan=".$itemCounter.">".$sno."</td>";
    echo "<td bgcolor='#C8E3FF' rowspan=".$itemCounter.">".$row['partyName']."</td>";

    while($row2 = mysqli_fetch_array($itemquery))
    {
        $itemNo++;
        echo "<td bgcolor='#C8E3FF'>".$itemNo."</td>";
        echo "<td bgcolor='#C8E3FF'>".$row2['date']."</td>";


            //$flower = $flower + $row2['flower'];
            echo "<td>".$row2['flower']."</td>";



        echo "<td  bgcolor='#C8E3FF'>".$row2['lotno']."</td>";
        echo "<td bgcolor='#C8E3FF'>".$row2['avgwt']."</td>";
        if ($row2['totalWeight'] == 0)
        {
            echo "<td  bgcolor='#C8E3FF'> </td>";
        }
        else{
            $totalWt = $totalWt + $row2['totalWeight'];
            echo "<td  bgcolor='#C8E3FF'>".$row2['totalWeight']."</td>";    
        }

        echo "<td  bgcolor='#C8E3FF'>".$row2['detailPage']."</td>";
        echo "</tr>";
    }
    echo "<td bgcolor='#C8E3FF'><b>Total</b></td>";


    echo "<td><b>".$flower."</b></td>";



        echo "<td bgcolor='#C8E3FF'></td>";
        echo "<td bgcolor='#C8E3FF'></td>";

            echo "<td bgcolor='#C8E3FF'><b>".$totalWt."</b></td>";  

        echo "<td  bgcolor='#C8E3FF'></td>";
        echo "</tr>";
        echo "<tr></tr><tr></tr><tr></tr><tr></tr><tr></tr>";

}
echo "</tbody></table>";
```

Answer (score 2):

As far as I know, if you properly use the THEAD section in the table, that header will be repeated on each page.

http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/struct/tables.html#h-11.2.3

added from http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_thead.asp:

Definition and Usage

The  tag is used to group header content in an HTML table.

The  element is used in conjunction with the  and  elements to specify each part of a table (header, body, footer).

Browsers can use these elements to enable scrolling of the table body independently of the header and footer. Also, when printing a large table that spans multiple pages, these elements can enable the table header and footer to be printed at the top and bottom of each page.

The  tag must be used in the following context: As a child of a  element, after any , and  elements, and before any , , and  elements.